# Too many redirects error while trying to configure rails application as SSL using Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, puma

When I hit my mydomain, as I can see from developer tools, it sends multiple requests.
My requirement is to add ssl, and it should redirect to https.

Project is running in Production mode.

**mydomain.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias domain.com
    
    Redirect  / https://dev.getshuffle.com/

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia Full
    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/

    <Directory "/var/www/my_project/public">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/chain.pem
    
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia Full
    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>
        
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
  
    <Directory "/var/www/my_project/public">
        AllowOverride All
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**production.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do    
  config.cache_classes = true
      config.eager_load = true
      config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
      config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
      config.serve_static_assets = false
      config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
      config.assets.compile = false
      config.assets.digest = true
      config.assets.version = '1.0'    
  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
      config.force_ssl = true
end
```

Comment: In mydomain.com, you have a `Redirect` directive, *then* the proxy!?!  Do one or the other.  If it still fails, put your logs in debug mode, setup one log for :80, another one for :443, run tests and post the logs here.

Comment: @Nic3500, Thank you for your response. For time being i commented out config.force_ssl and made changes in mydomain.conf, and its working now.